# How to use Spring/MongoDB in a Restful service with JSONApi Formatting

Tags: ember.js, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

Hello fellow developers!

I am using a Spring backend with MongoDB for a Rest based service as described here:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/

This is a great way to create powerful rest services and I would like to continue to use it, but I am having problems with its formatting of the JSON, for consumption by an Ember front end.

I really want to make my restful services on the back end return JSONApi.org formatting and not have to play tricks in Ember to massage the data.

I'm sure others must have encountered this very same problem and there is some community based solution, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Also, is there a community of people using Ember + Spring Rest? Or am I alone? :D

Thanks!

Peter

Comment: Have you tried [ember-json-api](https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api)? It’s an Ember Data adapter for JSON API.

Comment: Buck thanks for that info. This statement from that project does concern me though: "This adapter has preliminary support for URL-style JSON API. It currently only serializes one route per type, so if you have multiple ways to get a resource, it will not work as expected." I'm opening to trying this out but I believe that the right answer is in modifying the underlying Spring Rest formatter. I'm just not sure how that is done. :D

Comment: Has anyone tried this technique mentioned in an earlier post? Do I put this in Beans.xml? Also, it's labeled as a deprecated method:                                                               ' <bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>'

Comment: Since SDR 2.2 HAL is the choice for formatting response, optionally you set it regular json. That said, JSONAPI is indeed different format (different media type). So I doubt it you could have success with your effort.